# Efficiently flagging results

Tags: java

I have a bunch of objects floating around, let's call them orders. Being processed. However the rule of my (test) system is that in order to verify the results, I need the output in sequential (by order ID) order.

this means that an order that has been flagged that it is ready to be completed (finished processing), cannot be marked as completed unless all orders with order IDs < than its id have already been completed.

- orders can be flagged finished processing in any random order
- order ids are unique and assigned in the order of initial order creation

  class Order {
      int id;
      boolean finishedProcessing = false; 
      boolean completed = false;
  }

Can someone suggest an efficient solution to this problem? I can only think of creating a HashMap (order id, completed) and flagging an order completed in the map as each order completes and to determine if an order is allowed to complete then looping the entire map to see if all preceeding orders have been flagged completed.

It is the last part that bugs mean, seems very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: why can't you use an observer or event bus model whereby the lower order number orders inform the higher order number object that it can move forward?

Comment: Why not just keep track of the last processed id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If id's are assigned in order of creation, add the orders to a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) when created. The `Deque` will then implicitly be ordered by ID.

Whenever an order is marked complete, check the first entry in the Deque. If it is complete, remove it from the `Deque` (or move it to another one). Then check next (now first) entry in the Deque again, in case multiple orders are ready, and repeat as needed.

That `Deque` of incomplete orders is maintained independently of any `Map` you might need for looking up the order by ID.